# Seaborn kdeplot change title

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
sns.set_style("darkgrid")

s1, s2 = 5, 3
fig, axes = plt.subplots(s1, s2, figsize=(4*5, 5*5), sharey=True)
fig.suptitle(t="Suptitle", x=0.5, y=1-0.075, fontsize=40)
for ind1 in range(s1):
    for ind2 in range(s2):
        data=np.random.normal(size=100)
        sns.kdeplot(data, ax=axes[ind1, ind2], bw_adjust=1, 
                    linewidth=0.9, color="C9", alpha=0.5)
for ax, col in zip(axes[0], ["column_%d" %i for i in range(s2)]):
    ax.set_title(col, size=25)
for ax, row in zip(axes[:,-1], ["row_%d" %i for i in range(s1)]):
    ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
    ax.set_ylabel(row, rotation=90, size=25)

fig.text(0.5, 0.075, 'Common x label', ha='center', size = 30)
fig.text(0.065, 0.5, 'Common y label', va='center', rotation='vertical', size = 30)
fig.show()
```

I expect to see Something like this: [image: Expectation].

Bur really seaborn.kdeplot breaks my picture: it changes y label and writes the word "Density" on the left hand instead of uses my own title (row0, ..., row3) on the right hand: [image: harsh reality]

How can I fix it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I could not find an easy way to add a label to the right side of the subplot sharing the y-axis. What if I put density on the right side with `ax.text()` and update the density on the left side to row_1 row_2...?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the ylabel to the right because you are using subplot with shared y.

To get the plot you want, you can set the ylabels to be blank, and add the ylabel as text on the defined subplots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
sns.set_style("darkgrid")

s1, s2 = 5, 3
fig, axes = plt.subplots(s1, s2, figsize=(4*5, 5*5), sharey=True)
fig.suptitle(t="Suptitle", x=0.5, y=1-0.075, fontsize=40)
for ind1 in range(s1):
    for ind2 in range(s2):
        data=np.random.normal(size=100)
        sns.kdeplot(data, ax=axes[ind1, ind2], bw_adjust=1, 
                    linewidth=0.9, color="C9", alpha=0.5)
        axes[ind1, ind2].set_ylabel("")

for ax, col in zip(axes[0], ["column_%d" %i for i in range(s2)]):
    ax.set_title(col, size=25)
for ax, row in zip(axes[:,-1], ["row_%d" %i for i in range(s1)]):
    ax.text(1, 0.5, row, horizontalalignment='left',
            verticalalignment='center',rotation = 'vertical',
            size = 25,transform=ax.transAxes)

fig.text(0.5, 0.075, 'Common x label', ha='center', size = 30)
fig.text(0.065, 0.5, 'Common y label', va='center', rotation='vertical', size = 30)
fig.show()
```

[image]